# WiX toolset: how to pass a commandline argument to the installed application?

Tags: installation, wix

I have my WiX installer up-and-running: it installs and starts my application. So far so good.

But I want my application to know it has been started by the installer (so it can get the user to fill in some needed parameters).

So, is there a way to add a command-line parameter to the starting application?

As everybody does, I of course used (sorry for  the malforming):

```
 Property Id="WixShellExecTarget" Value="[#filA998797898798798798798]" 
    CustomAction Id="LaunchApplication" BinaryKey="WixCA" 
 DllEntry="WixShellExec" Impersonate="yes" />
```

I found an article where somebody had the exact same question and had found an answer in using a different custom action (I guess by implementing the 'ExeCommand' parameter) but he didn't update his article to tell us what he had done exactly! Can anybody help?

Note: the article I referred to:

http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Passing-command-line-arguments-to-an-app-launched-after-setup-td1366362.html

Comment: Check a flag in HKCU registry to determine if this is the first application launch?

Comment: For now I set a flag in the app.config, that's even easier then use the registry. But ideally I pass a commandline parameter to my app and the other poster did manage that through th wix, so that's what i'm looking for.